# Programming Error for Aggregate Function

Tags: mysql, ms-access, aggregate

```
SELECT ID, AppID, Description, Min([Transaction Date]) AS Expr1 
FROM AppProsHist 
WHERE [Description]=[Non-Final Rejections]
```

I keep getting the error message:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression "ID" as part of an aggregate function.

It also says it about "AppID" What do I do? I'm generally confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause for all non-aggregated columns.
This could look something like this for your query:

```
SELECT ID, AppID, Description, Min([Transaction Date]) AS Expr1
FROM AppProsHist
WHERE [Description]='Non-Final Rejections'
GROUP BY ID, AppID, Description
```

However, chances are this won't get you your desired result, since Description may be very unique for each row. So you may also want to exclude Description from the query, unless it is unique enough to be here.

See also the [MySQL Reference for GROUP BY (Aggregate) Function Descriptions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) and the [MSDN Reference for Aggregate Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/en-en/library/ms173454.aspx).

Comment: Now a message pops up wanting a parameter value for Non-Final Rejections. What might they want me to put in there? I feel like this is just an access issue.

Comment: Did you use single quotes like so: 'Non-Final Rejections' as I did in my answer? Otherwise you are prompted to specify the value for the description.

Answer (score 0):

Using MIN (or MAX, or AVG, etc.) functions, you are using what is known as an aggregate function. These functions, to put it simply, work on multiple records at a time. However, they cannot work (and throw the above exception) on a single record, because the MIN of one record is always the same.

Whenever you use any type of grouping or aggregation, all items in the query must also be a part of an aggregate function or grouping. As below:

```
SELECT ID, AppID, Description, Min([Transaction Date]) AS Expr1 
FROM AppProsHist 
WHERE [Description]=[Non-Final Rejections] 
GROUP BY ID, AppID, Description
```